# How to set current datetime in gremlin console?

Tags: datetime, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython

How to set current DateTime in the gremlin console?

I need to add an audit field `created_on` with `current_timestamp` as default value

Eg:

```
g.addV('student').property('name', 'Thirumal').property('created_on', datetime())
```

In, the above query, I am getting an error on `datetime()`. What is the syntax to add default date time?

Answer (score 1):

In the Gremlin Console, you can use `new Date()` if you do not have a version that supports `datetime()`. Note that `datetime()` was recently added to Gremlin so you may not have the version that contains it yet. I believe it was added in the 3.5.2 release. Also please see [this discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@tinkerpop.apache.org/msg33162.html)

Without `datetime()` you can still do

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('date', new Date())
==>v[61287]

gremlin> g.V(61287).valueMap()
==>[date:[Thu Feb 10 10:02:18 CST 2022]]
```

UPDATED based on comments:

If you are using Amazon Neptune, the database provides its own version of the `datetime` function that expects an ISO 8601 compliant date string. So you can do something like this:

```java
g.addV('test').property('date', datetime('2022-02-10'))
```

If you are using Neptune's Jupyter notebooks, to set the current date, you can create a date in a cell above (using Python) of the form

```
my_date = # some date calculation that yields an ISO string.
```

or, more concretely:

```
import datetime
d=datetime.datetime.now()
my_date = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and inject that string like this:

```java
g.addV('test').property('date', datetime('${my_date}'))
```

Comment: The date is not recognising, `Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 36, error message : token recognition error at: 'D'`.

Comment: Which back end database are you using?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook to connect to neptune

Comment: database -> AWS Neptune

Comment: Ah OK - I did not see Neptune in the tags. I added one. I'll update the answer.